# DependencyProperty default value depends on coercion logic

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this simple example in the ViewModel of a WPF application:

```
class VM_DiskPartition : DependencyObject
{
        // (...) Other properties

        public bool IsLowOnSpace
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsLowOnSpaceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsLowOnSpaceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLowOnSpaceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsLowOnSpace", typeof(bool), typeof(VM_DiskPartition), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnLowOnSpaceChanged));
        private static void OnLowOnSpaceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            ((VM_DiskPartition)d).CoerceValue(BgColorProperty);
        }


        public Brush BgColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BgColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BgColorProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BgColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BgColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(VM_DiskPartition), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red, null, Coerce_BgColor));
        private static object Coerce_BgColor(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            return UIUtils.GetBgColor(((VM_DiskPartition)d).IsLowOnSpace);
        }

}
```

I want the BgColor property to have its default value automatically set by its coercion function.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this instead of calling `CoerceValue(BgColorProperty)` from the constructor?
The reason is that I may have many properties like this in the future and it doesn't look very clean to use a lot of CoerceValue() calls in the constructor.

Maybe it's better to use Converters in this scenario? I was trying to go without them and create new ViewModel properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be somewhat confused... the `DependencyObject` and `DependencyProperty` classes are UI classes. They don't belong in a view model. In view models, we use normal CLR properties and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to handle property change notification. Therefore, there's no need to use them in a view model at all.

If you want to set a default value in a view model, you simply do this:

```
private int number = 5; // <-- default value

public int Number
{ 
    get { return number; }
    set { number = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Number"); }
}
```

If you want property value coercion in a view model, you just do this:

```
public int Number
{ 
    get { return number; }
    set { number = Math.Max(0, value); NotifyPropertyChanged("Number"); }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Looking again at your code, it occurs to me that it shouldn't be in a view model at all. It looks like it should be in the code behind of some `UserControl`. We put *data* in view models, not *UI elements* like `Brush`es. If you want to set a default value for a `DependencyProperty`, the correct way to do it *is* how you have shown us:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BgColorProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("BgColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(VM_DiskPartition), 
    new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red/* <-- default value */, null, Coerce_BgColor));
```

Property coercion is for ensuring that a value stays within certain bounds like the example I gave above that ensures that the value will never be negative.

Comment: I was under the impression that there are two ways to design the view model: The INotifyPropertyChanged way and the DependencyObject way: http://kentb.blogspot.ro/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html

Comment: `DependencyObject` and `DependencyProperty` are *not* UI classes.

Comment: They are typically only used by UI classes, such as UI controls.